# how to loop through array of arrays and combine values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, linq.js

I need to loop through a array of arrays and calculate the sum of each array. The Json is a kendo-ui chart series with arrays of x,y coordinates. I need to return the sum of the x,y values. linq.js or javascript will work. thanks
JSON

```
var =series = [{
"style":"smooth",
"color":"blue",
"data":[
    [600,30000],
    [800,60000],
    [1100,100000]
],
"name":"Subject Property",
"removeByNames":[
    ["Product1"],
    ["Product2"],
    ["Product3"]
],
 "$$hashKey":"object:30"
}]
```

So for this example i would need to end up with this

```
var newSeries = [{
"style":"smooth",
"color":"blue",
"data":[
    [30600],
    [60800],
    [101100]
],
"name":"Subject Property",
"removeByNames":[
    ["Product1"],
    ["Product2"],
    ["Product3"]
],
"$$hashKey":"object:30"
}]
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I have been trying with these two examples http://jsfiddle.net/kv854c61/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(var i=0;i<series[0].data.length;i++){
   var val = series[0].data[i];
   newSeries.data[i] = val[0] + val[1];
}
```

Comment: this will only loop through the first 'data' set in the series array, you need to loop through each object in the 'series' array if you have more than one object - and if you don't have more than one object, why on earth is it in an array?

Answer (score 1):

You can use loop and use `reduce`

```
var series = [{
            ...
}]

for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < series[i].data.length; j++) {
        series[i].data[j] = series[i].data[j].reduce(function(p,c) {
            return p + c;
        });
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kv854c61/1/

Answer (score 1):

you just need to loop the values in your data properties something like this..

```
for( var i - 0; i < series.length-1; i++){
  for( var j - 0; j < series[i].data.length-1; i++){
    var result = series[i].data[j][0] + series[i].data[j][1];
    series[i].data[j] = result;
  }
}
```

now it would make sense to add the new data array, so as not to overwrite

```
series[i].new_data[j] = result;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.map` is quite useful in this case:

```
// extracts the data entries of each item in the series
var data = series.map(function(item){ return item["data"]; });

function sum(point) {
    return point[0] + point[1];

    // in case point is of arbitrary dimension use Array.reduce:
    // return point.reduce(function(prev, cur){ return prev + cur; }, 0);
}

var sums = data.map(function(arr){
    return arr.map(function(point){
        return sum(point);
    });
});

// sums now contains an array of array of sums
// e.g. [[30600,60800,101100]]
```